# Changes remain permanently for replace?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can any one tell me the difference between replace function & translate function of Oracle?

I read somewhere that replace makes the changes in database permanent where translate does not, is it correct?

Can any one show the query which will prove that replace does changes permanently in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between REPLACE and TRANSLATE:

- REPLACE substitutes one string for another string.
- TRANSLATE substitutes characters in one set for those in another.
- Neither TRANSLATE or REPLACE update the database.

Here's some examples:

```
create table nada (id number(8), description nvarchar2(30));
insert into nada values (1, "I like peanuts.");
insert into nada values (2, 'Peanuts are not a nut.');
insert into nada values (3, 'peanuts are a legume.');
commit;
select * from nada;
```

```
Id Description
-- ------------------------
 1 I like peanuts.
 2 Peanuts are not a nut.
 3 peanuts are a legume.
```

**REPLACE** works like this:

```
select replace(description, 'peanuts', 'tomatoes') from nada;
```

gives:

```
replace(description,'peanuts','tomatoes')
--------------------------------------
I like tomatoes.
Peanuts are not a nut.
tomatoes are a legume.
```

Just the word 'peanuts' is replaced with 'tomatoes'. It's case sensitive so 'Peanuts' isn't replaced.

**TRANSLATE** works like this:

```
select translate(description, ' .', '_!') from nada;
```

```
translate(description, ' .', '_!')
----------------------------------
I_like_peanuts!
Peanuts_are_not_a_nut!
peanuts_are_a_legume!
```

All spaces are changed to underscores **and** all periods are changed to bangs!

---

Neither TRANSLATE or REPLACE update the database. They just change the value
in a statement. Of course, you can use that value to update the database if
you want. For example:

```
select replace(description, 'peanuts', 'tomatoes') from nada;
select * from nada;
```

The table is **still the same**:

```
Id Description
-- ------------------------
 1 I like peanuts.
 2 Peanuts are not a nut.
 3 peanuts are a legume.
```

If you want to change the table, put it in an UPDATE or INSERT statement,
such as:

```
update nada set description = replace(description, 'peanuts', 'tomatoes');
commit;
```

Now it's changed:

```
select * from nada;
```

```
Id Description
-- ------------------------
 1 I like tomatoes.
 2 Peanuts are not a nut.
 3 tomatoes are a legume.
```

Now if you want to fix 'Peanuts' too, you can use REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: What will happen if you use update statement with translate clause. Will it still update the record? Can you show an example for that as well?

Comment: I'm assuming that updates would be done to the database when you use translate with update command. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Neither function makes permanent changes -- only when using an `UPDATE`, and after committing the transaction, is a "permanent" change made... Until the next update statement is run on that column ;)

The two functions operate differently:

```
SELECT translate('1tech23', '123', '456') AS translate,
       replace('1tech23', '123', '456') AS replace
  FROM DUAL
```

...returns:

```
translate  replace
-------------------
4tech56    1tech23
```

[REPLACE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) replaces the provided pattern; [TRANSLATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) iterates over the string to process the replace character at a time (moving left to right)

Comment: Ponies: If you look at below URL, it says that replace changes database & thats why I was confused...Can you confirm which one is true? `http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/25173#.ThE57GGQpvk`

Comment: @Mike: "gomathi.e"'s answer is incorrect; the rest of the answers say the same as mine.